# Change UIImageView size programmatically without changing position

Tags: swift, uiimage, cgrect

I want to chance a UIImageView size without changing the UIImageView Location. This is what i got so far: 
`Person_1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)`

I don't want the x and y to be 0. I want the UIImageView on the same place but bigger. Please help!

Comment: Please clarify. Are you trying to create an animation of some kind? Make the image zoom in? It’s really unclear what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it by way of changing the frame, then it would look something like:

```
Person_1.frame = CGRect(x: Person_1.frame.origin.x, y: Person_1.frame.origin.y, width: 200, height: 200)
```

Is there a reason you wouldn't be doing it by way of constraints/AutoLayout?